# Compile errors with Angular 2 and TypeScript in Eclipse

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, typescript, angular

Which development environments for TypeScript support the right version of the language for developing with AngularJS 2, and are likely to keep up with new releases? My preferred IDE is Eclipse.

I was originally trying to use the TypEcs plugin in Eclipse (http://typecsdev.com/) but the latest version runs TypeScript 1.5.3 and abstract classes used by Angular weren't introduced until TypeScript 1.6 (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript).

Comment: Not an actual answer to your question... But why don't your try Visual Studio Code? Once I tried it, I loved it ;) Really easy, just download and use!

Comment: I'm using Eclipse for back end and all other development, so I'd prefer to stick with it. Have used Visual Studio in the distant past so not opposed to it in principle, but would only complicate my current stack with it as a last resort.

Comment: Completely rewrote the original question -- my compile errors were due to wrong version of TypeScript.

Comment: I am using `WebStorm` from JetBrains for my Angular 2 development - it does all the auto completion, code generation and linting for me. Used VSCode before that, but it was too simplistic for my needs.

Comment: @Peter I'm working on Angular2 Eclipse https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse which is based on https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Getting-Started You can choose version of typescript https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Configuration#compile that you can install with "npm install typescript"

Comment: Thanks Angelo, tried it out. If you write that up as an answer I'll choose it. Meanwhile, I'll ask some questions over on your repo.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [Angular2 Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started)

I suggest you try [Angular2 Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started):

- it is based on [TypeScript IDE](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Getting-Started) for [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) support.
- it integrates [angular-cli](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/AngularCLI) with [Terminal](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/ngTerminal), [Wizards](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/ngWizards) and [Launches](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/ngLaunches).
- it extends WTP HTML Editor to support [Angular2 syntax inside the HTML editor](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/HTML-Editor).

Angular2 Eclipse requires `Eclipse JEE Neon` installation.